# Why this List of FlowLayoutPanels is being drawn in a weird pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, c#-4.0, flowlayoutpanel

I have a program that adds small `FlowLayoutPanels` to a larger `Panel`, or at least that's the intent. Each `FlowLayoutPanel` contains several other simple `Controls`, and is stored in a `List<FlowLayoutPanel>` named skillPanels.

When the button is clicked to add a new `FlowLayoutPanel` to the `Panel`, one is generated and stored in skillPanels. skillPanels is then deep copied to a holder (named, err... holder), then trashed completely to get rid of the `FlowLayoutPanels` visible in the UI- every FlowLayoutPanel has its children Dispose-d, then is Disposed itself. For good measure, the List is then .Clear()-ed.

After cleaning the slate, holder is deep copied back into skillPanels, which is then iterated over it and adds its members to the larger `Panel`, positioning each by hand as I don't trust layout managers as far as I can throw them. This level of circuitousness is sadly need for a for-each-FlowLayoutPanel remove method that will be added in the future. By stepping through the code and providing `MessageBoxes`, I know for certain that each one is added to the larger `Panel`.

But here's the kicker: despite `.Add`-ing to the `Panel`, only some of them show up. I suspect the `.Dispose` method is to blame somehow, but I can't explain how or why.

For my own sanity, as well as a degree of clarity, this is the pattern of which `FlowLayoutPanel` is visible after which clicks:

1st add: 1

2nd add: 2 (i.e. 1 has disappeared)

3rd add: 2, 3

4th add: 2, 4

5th add: 2, 4, 5

6th add: 4, 6

7th add: 4, 6, 7

8th add: 6, 8

9th add: 6, 8, 9

See a pattern forming?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<FlowLayoutPanel> skillPanels = new List<FlowLayoutPanel>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Panel pnlMacroSkillsPanel = new Panel();
            pnlMacroSkillsPanel.Height = this.Height;
            pnlMacroSkillsPanel.Width = this.Width;
            Button btnAddSkill = new Button();
            btnAddSkill.Click += new EventHandler(btnAddSkill_Click);
            pnlMacroSkillsPanel.Controls.Add(btnAddSkill);
            this.Controls.Add(pnlMacroSkillsPanel);            
        }

        void reDrawSkillPanels(Panel pan)
        {
            FlowLayoutPanel plato = new FlowLayoutPanel();
            List<FlowLayoutPanel> holder = new List<FlowLayoutPanel>(skillPanels.Count);
            foreach (FlowLayoutPanel f in skillPanels)
            {
                holder.Add(f);
            }
            try
            {
                foreach (object f in pan.Controls)
                {
                    if (f is FlowLayoutPanel)
                    {
                        plato = (FlowLayoutPanel)f;
                        MessageBox.Show("Disposing of FlowLayoutPanel");
                        foreach (Control c in plato.Controls)
                        {
                            c.Dispose();
                        }
                        ((FlowLayoutPanel)f).Dispose();
                    }
                }
                skillPanels.Clear();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //
            }
            foreach (FlowLayoutPanel f in holder)
            {
                skillPanels.Add(f);
            }
            holder.Clear();
            int initialYoffset = 40;
            for (int count = 0; count < skillPanels.Count; count++)
            {
                plato = new FlowLayoutPanel();
                plato = skillPanels[count];
                plato.Top = initialYoffset + ((plato.Height + 4) * count);
                plato.Left = 4;
                //MessageBox.Show("Adding skillPanels member at: 4, " + (initialYoffset + ((skillPanels[count].Height + 4) * count)) + "!");
                //MessageBox.Show("ToString:" + skillPanels[count].ToString() + ", Width: " + skillPanels[count].Width);
                pan.Controls.Add(plato);
            }
            //MessageBox.Show("skillPanels.Count = " + skillPanels.Count);
        }

        void btnAddSkill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button plato = (Button)sender;
            FlowLayoutPanel pnlNewSkill = new FlowLayoutPanel
            pnlNewSkill.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
            pnlNewSkill.Height = 30;
            pnlNewSkill.Width = 350;
            Random r = new Random();
            Color randomColor = Color.FromArgb(r.Next(255), r.Next(255), r.Next(255));
            pnlNewSkill.BackColor = randomColor;
            /*
             * Code creating and adding Controls to pnlNewPanel would go here
             */
            skillPanels.Add(pnlNewSkill);
            reDrawSkillPanels(((Panel)(plato.Parent)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At first glance I see no dispose of what each `FlowLayoutPanel` contains.  That would not be automatic.  You might be piling up handles.

Comment: Tried adding it in my non-edited version, no effect. Will add it to the above, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a panel to your list `skillPanels` it remains there, even when you add it with `pan.Controls.Add` later. So when the second click occurs you `Dispose` it, and then add it again, along with the new panel. After the third click you `Dispose` the second one, and now your list contains 2 disposed panels and one new. All of them you add to `pan`, etc.

So basically, you're piling up disposed panels in the `skillPanels` list and then you keep readding them to `pan.Controls` in your `for` loop, despite the fact that they've been disposed.

Not sure what do you need the list for - you could just add the new panel in the `btnAddSkill_Click` directly. Another possibility is to remove them from your list, either after you add it to `pan.Controls` or when you dispose them.